# Average of histogram estimator

Tags: statistics

I am studying for a statistics course. We would like to estimate an unknown probability density function $f$. Let us consider a random sample $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ drawn from $f$. In the lecture notes, the histogram estimator is defined as
$$\hat{f}_{nha} ^{hist} = \frac{1}{nh} \sum _{k\in \mathbb{Z}} N_{kha} \mathbf{1} (\cdot \in (a+kh, a + (k+1)h] ),$$
where $h>0$ is the bin width, $a\in [0,h)$ a parameter that defines where to include the jumps, $n$ the sample size, $k$ any integer, $N_{kha} := \# \{ i : X_i \in (a+kh, a+(k+1)h] \}$ the number of observations in the interval $(a+kh, a+(k+1)h]$, and where $\mathbf{1} (\cdot \in (a+kh, a + (k+1)h] )$ is an indicator function for the interval $(a+kh, a + (k+1)h]$.

[image]

The choice of $a$ seems to be quite arbitrary. However, we can consider the average $\hat f _{nh} = h^{-1} \int _0 ^{h} \hat f ^{hist} _{nha} da$ over all choices of $a$, so that we do not have to make a choice for $a$.

According to the lecture notes it can be shown that
$$\hat f _{nh} (x) = \frac{1}{nh} \sum _{i=1} ^n \left ( 1 - \frac{|X_i - x|}{h} \right ) _+,$$
which is the kernel density estimator with triangular kernel $K(u)=(1-|u|)_+$.

I try to figure out how this can be shown. My idea is to write $N_{kha} = \sum _i \mathbf{1} (X_i \in (a+kh, a + (k+1)h] )$ and to use that only finitely many $N_{kha}$'s are non-zero so that I can pull in the integral into the summations. However, I do not know how to proceed further. Does someone have any hints?

Comment: Histogram estimator of what?

Comment: of the density $f$

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to view a histogram as an estimator of the density function of the population from which a random sample is taken. There are various rules suggesting the number of histogram bins, based on sample size, it order to make histograms useful for that purpose. [One example is the [Freedman-Diaconis rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedman%E2%80%93Diaconis_rule).]

I'm not sure I follow your notation or the method you are using. If you can edit your question to define $a, n, k, h,$ etc. maybe someone will give a direct answer.

However, I want to make sure you know about kernel density estimators (KDEs), which use data to estimate the population density function--without regard to whatever histogram you choose to make. I will illustrate the use of a KDE so you can see the result, and you can read details online, if interested.

Suppose we have a random sample of size $n = 1000$ from
a population distributed as $\mathsf{Gamma}(\mathrm{shape}=5, \mathrm{rate}=0.1),$ The figure
below shows (a) a density histogram from R of the sample,
(b) the density function (dotted curve) of $\mathsf{Gamma}5, .01),$ which would not be known is a real application, and (c) the default KDE from R for this sample.

```
set.seed(2020)
x = rgamma(1000, 5, 0.1)
hist(x, prob=T, br=20, col="skyblue2", 
     main="n = 1000: GAMMA(5, 0.1)")
 curve(dgamma(x, 5, 0.1), add=T, lwd=2, lty="dotted")
 lines(density(x), lwd=2, col="orange")
```

[image]

As you can see, the KDE is very close to the true population density.
From the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) page on gamma distributions, you can see that the mode of this distribution is $\delta=40.$ If you were to try to
estimate the mode from the histogram you would guess
somewhere between 30 and 40.

The KDE averages together kernels of a particular shape, which can be specified, to estimate the density function. In R, it consists of 512 x and y coordinates, from which
we can find its mode: about 37.5 (which is close to 40), and other features of the estimate.

```
kde = density(x);  kde

Call:
        density.default(x = x)

Data: x (1000 obs.);    Bandwidth 'bw' = 4.725

        x                 y            
 Min.   : -7.537   Min.   :1.264e-06  
 1st Qu.: 38.811   1st Qu.:1.976e-04  
 Median : 85.159   Median :1.714e-03  
 Mean   : 85.159   Mean   :5.389e-03  
 3rd Qu.:131.506   3rd Qu.:9.915e-03  
 Max.   :177.854   Max.   :1.961e-02  

mean(kde$x[kde$y==max(kde$y)])
[1] 37.45053
```

The figure below shows KDEs for samples of size $n = 200$ and $n = 5000$ from the same distribution.
Not surprisingly results are better for larger sample sizes. At left, tick marks along the horizontal axis show
actual positions of the 100 data values [made with `rug(x)`]; at right, the population density curve is not shown because it is
difficult to distinguish from the KDE. The R code for the figure is similar to the code shown above.

[image]

*References:* This [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) article gives an introductory discussion of KDEs, and many references; publications of Silverman and Wahba may be of particular interest.

Comment: Thank you for your extensive explanation. I have edited my question to clarify what is meant by $a,n,k,h,$ etc. The question is about an introductory text that motivates the use of kernel density estimators by stating that it can be shown that averaging the histogram estimator over $a$ (a parameter that defines the jump points of the bins with bin width $h$) yields a kernel density estimator with triangular kernel. However, I find it difficult to see how this can be shown. I am unable to technically prove the statement about averaging over $a$.